# Solve functional equation: $\frac{F(x)}{F(1)} = 2F\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{4a}\right)-F(x/a)$

Tags: functional-equations, recurrences

Solve this functional equation:

$$\frac{F(x)}{F(1)} = 2F\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{4a}\right)-F(x/a)$$

for $F(x)$ where $a > 0$ is a parameter. I know there is a trivial constant solution, $F(x) = 1$. Is there a non-constant solution?

Assume that $F(x)$ is continuous, and all the smoothness properties that you require to arrive to an answer. Note that I would accept the answer in the form of an infinite product or sum, or integral ....

I do not know if it has an analytical solution, and have no reason to expect that it does. It showed up in some calculations I was doing. But if there is a technique I can apply, it would be nice to know about it.

Comment: FWIW: There is at least one solution, $F(x)\equiv 1$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks, I knew that. Forgot to tell in the question I am looking for a non-trivial solution.

Comment: Why the downvote? Leave a comment

Comment: Oh, I got notified from that I comment and I thought you were referring to me. FWIW, the downvote is not mine.

Comment: Please, do not pose the question in a way it looks like an exercise. That will avoid downvotes.

Comment: For the case $a=1$ there are infinitely many solutions, at least as long as you do not require any continuity properties. The easiest one $F(-3)=F(1)=1$ and $F(x) = c$ for all other $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for an arbitrary constant $c$.

Comment: @FernandoMuro What do yo mean? It is not an exercise.

Comment: @StephanSturm I added a continuity requirement.

Answer (score 2):

(A very partial answer.) I would like to point out that the case $a=1$ is special.
In this case, we immediately have $F(1)=1$ and 
$$F(x)=F\left(\frac{(1+x)^2}{4}\right).$$
Near the point $x=1$ there aren't any smooth solutions besides the trivial one.